# Making Group member's view Page who joined the group

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a group profile where user can view the members of any group who has joined that group. but problem is that When I am using my query it is not working correct it is showing who also have the request to join but not accepted that group and I want to show only who have joined the group.
Here is the query:

```
 $grprqstprofile=mysqli_query($connect,
                "select UserLogin.User_No, UserLogin.Fist_Name, 
                        UserLogin.Last_Name, UserLogin.Profile, 
                        UserLogin.Designation, UserLogin.ProfileDP, 
                        GroupRqst.grprqst_SNo, GroupRqst.Group_Id, 
                        GroupRqst.Group_Admin, GroupRqst.Grouprqst_Receiver, 
                        GroupRqst.Grouprqst_Sender, GroupRqst.Group_Status 
                FROM UserLogin 
                    INNER JOIN GroupRqst ON UserLogin.User_No = GroupRqst.Grouprqst_Receiver 
                WHERE Grouprqst_Receiver='$user_id' 
                  AND Group_Id='$grpviewerid' 
                  AND Group_Status='1'");
```

`UserLogin` is the table containing the information who has their ID with this site.

`GroupRqst` is the table containing the information with group's member request.

`$grpviewerid` is getting the Grou_Id from another page using get `function { @$grpviewerid = $_GET['gid']; }`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: So what condition indicates `accepted`

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the where statement you should try absolute table names like this

```
WHERE GroupRqst.Grouprqst_Receiver='$user_id' 
AND GroupRqst.Group_Id='$grpviewerid' 
AND GroupRqst.Group_Status='1'
```

Source: Own experience